# I'm very new to making discord bots with python and for some reason the bot doesn't respond to commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

As described in the title, I am new to Python(programming in general) and I tried making a bot, however the bot does not respond to commands. I followed/looked through multiple youtube tutorials & articles, but I cannot find a way to fix my problem.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("kram is now online")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="This bot is a WIP"))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:

        @bot.command(aliases=["gp"])
        async def ghostping(ctx, amount=2):
            await ctx.send("@everyone")
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)

        @bot.command()
        async def help(ctx):
            await ctx.send("As of right now, .gp is the only working command.")

bot.run("I'm hiding my token")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to single out your problem better (Any errors? Also refer to [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)) so that you can ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey why don't you try this instead the same thing but i removed the on message

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("kram is now online")
     await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="This bot is a WIP"))


@bot.command(aliases=["gp"])
async def ghostping(ctx, amount=2):
      await ctx.send("@everyone")
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
      await ctx.send("As of right now, .gp is the only working command.")

bot.run("I'm hiding my token")
```

This should work as when using cogs and when you have a command there is no need to put it in the on_message event. i suggest you watch this series(Really helpful while starting out):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrHbGhem6I4&list=UUR-zOCvDCayyYy1flR5qaAg

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out that somewhat simple solution fixed all my problems, again thank you and have a good day!

Comment: You might wanna mark it as completed if your good with this answer